# React JS import error - Module not found: You attempted to import ../actions which falls outside of the project src/ directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, path, action

I am building a Spotify Application with their web API and am running the front end with React. I am importing my actions to my component, but I get this error

Failed to Compile

./src/SearchBar.js
Module not found: You attempted to import ../actions which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported. You can either move it inside src/, or add a symlink to it from project's node_modules/.

But my actions folder is 100% within my src directory of my client. I have imported Actions in the past, but for some reason it's different, does it have something to do with my server?

[image: Screen of my directory]

Thanks for checking it out!

Comment: `../` refers to the parent directory, not the current directory.

Answer (score 4):

When you use `../` you're trying to access to the parent folder. That's why now you're out of the src folder.

If you want to import something at the same level, you should use `./` In your case `./actions/yourFile`